# Vue - Instantiate component in custom directive

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-directives

I want protect some actions that require authentication by showing a popover to sign in/register to unauthenticated users.

I would like to have something like this :

```
<button require-auth>Like</button>
```

When you click on it without being authenticated, a popover appear (I'm using the Bootstrap Vue popover) that tell you to sign in to proceed.

To do so, I created a custom directive that listen to the click event and check the athentication status of the user. The problem is that I don't know how to instantiate the popover component from there and display it.

Actually here is what I tried without success :

```
export const Authenticated: DirectiveOptions = {
  bind (el, binding, vnode) {
    el.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
      if (store.getters['users/authenticated']) {
        return;
      }

      event.preventDefault();

      const node = document.createElement('div');

      const placement = get(binding, 'value', 'auto');
      const template = `
        <p>Vous devez être connecté pour effectuer cette action</p>
        <div>
          <b-button block :to="{ name: 'login' }">Se connecter</b-button>
          <b-button block :to="{ name: 'register' }">S'inscrire</b-button>
        </div>`;

      const popover = new BPopover({
        propsData: { target: el, placement },
      });

      popover.$slots.default = [template as any];
      popover.$slots.title = ['Connexion requise' as any];

      popover.$mount(node);
      popover.$emit('open');

      console.log(popover.$el) // which log : <---->
    })
  },
};
```

I know that I can do this with a component but I want it to work with any type of button and by doing so I'll have to use a slot and wrap  within a div, which will break the structure of the page.

How can I trigger the popover correctly ?

Answer (score 0):

In the popover: `v-if="notAuthenticated"`

On the button: `@click="checkAuth"`

In the hooks:

```
data() {
    return {
        notAuthenticated: false
    }
},
methods: {
    checkAuth () {
        if (this.isAuthenticated)
            //do whatever
        } else {
            this.notAuthenticated= true;
        }
    }
}
```

and change `notAuthenticated` back when popover closes, button clicked, etc.

Comment: I can manage the popover like that for each button but a page can have many actions like this, so I want to create a reusable directive that will automatically check and bind the popover to the element, rather than redefine the function and the template of the popover in each component